# Ajax output response in codeigniter controller

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter-3

i'm working codeiginter cart. im send cart data through Ajax request but in response output giving me many error i don't know why giving me syntax error help appreciated

> 1. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF Line Number: 873
> 2. Message: syntax error, unexpected 'form_hidden' (T_STRING)

```
$output = '';
            if(count($cart) == 0)
            { 
             $output .= '   <tr> 
                    <td colspan="8">
                        <div class="noitemcontent alert-dismissible alert-info">'
                        . $this->lang->line('sales_no_items_in_cart').
                     '</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>';
                 } else //
            {
                foreach(array_reverse($cart, true) as $line=>$item)
                {
                     form_open($controller_name."/edit_item/$line", array('class'=>'form-horizontal line-item', 'id'=>'cart_'.$line)) .
                '<tr>
                            <td> '
                             . anchor($controller_name."/delete_item/$line", '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>') .
                            '</td>
                            <td style="align: center;"> '.
                                $item['name'] .'

                            </td>';
                             if ($items_module_allowed) 
                            {                   
                $output .= '<td> '.
                    form_input(array
                    ('name'=>'price', 'class'=>'form-control input-sm cartline', 'value'=>to_currency_no_money($item['price']),
                    'tabindex'=>++$tabindex,
                    'data-form' => $line
                    ))  .'
            </td>';         }
                            else
                            {
                            $output .= '    <td> '.
                                      to_currency($item['price']).
                                      form_hidden('price', $item['price'])
                                . '</td> ';
                            }
                        $output .= ' <td>'.
                                 if($item['is_serialized']==1) //error Type: ParseError Message: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) 
                                {
                                    to_quantity_decimals($item['quantity'])
                                    form_hidden('quantity', $item['quantity']) //Message: syntax error, unexpected 'form_hidden' (T_STRING)
                                }
                                else
                                {                               
                        form_input(array('name'=>'quantity',
                         'id','quantity',
                         'type'=>'number',
                         'class'=>'form-control input-sm cartline',
                          'value'=>to_quantity_decimals($item['quantity']),
                          'tabindex'=>++$tabindex,
                           'data-form' => $line));
                                }.'
                                </td><td>';
    form_input(array('name'=>'discount', 
        'value'=>$item['discount'],
        //'type'=>'number',
        // 'min'=>0,
        // 'max'=>100,
        'title'=>'Discount (5 or 5%)',
        'tabindex'=>++$tabindex,
        'class'=>'form-control input-sm cartline',
        'data-form' => $line))

    $output .= '</td></tr><tr>'.
                            if($item['allow_alt_description']==1)
                            {
                            .'<td style="color: #2F4F4F;"> '.
                                $this->lang->line('sales_description_abbrv') .'</td>'.
                            }.'
                            <td colspan="2" style="text-align: left;">'.
                                if($item['allow_alt_description']==1) //error
                                {
                                    echo form_input(array('name'=>'description', 'class'=>'form-control input-sm', 'value'=>$item['description']))
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    if ($item['description']!='')
                                    {
                                        echo $item['description'];
                                        echo form_hidden('description', $item['description'])
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        $this->lang->line('sales_no_description')
                                        form_hidden('description','')
                                    }
                                }
                                .'
                            </td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td style="color: #2F4F4F;">'.
                                if($item['is_serialized']==1)
                                {
                                    $this->lang->line('sales_serial')
                                }.
                            '</td>
                            <td colspan="4" style="text-align: left;">'.
                                if($item['is_serialized']==1) 
                                {
                                    form_input(array('name'=>'serialnumber', 'class'=>'form-control input-sm', 'value'=>$item['serialnumber']))
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    form_hidden('serialnumber', '')
                                }
                                .'
                            </td>
                        </tr>';
                    form_close()                    
                }
            }
            echo $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed `;` to divide lines. Or `.` if you would like to concatenate these lines as you are doing few lines later.

Additionally you cannot concatenate string and if statement(not directly). Replace dot with semicolon before your if where you have unexpected if statement.